# Error installing nokogiri

Tags: software-installation

I get this following when I try to install nokigiri,

```
 Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.9.1/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.4 -r ./siteconf20181224-15718-15hfw3z.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.9.1/gem_make.out
```

I have tried installing `ruby-dev1`, `zlib1g-dev` and `liblzma-dev`, didn't help. I also installed `build-essential patch`, `ruby-dev` version `2.0.0`,`2.0.2`,`2.0.3` that also didn't help.

Comment: This looks like it expects a newer ruby version, have you tried installing ruby2.4-dev?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing `ruby2.4-dev` did the work.